# Oninput display HTML code (conditional)

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I am creating a HTML form in which I would like to display as many input fields for text as they select with a number-input. I will have this:

```
<input type="number" name="syggrafei"  oninput="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" /><div id="div1"></div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
<script>
function showfield(value) {
    if (value == '1') {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="syggrafea1" placeholder="S????af?a? 1" />';
    }
    else if (value == '2') {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="syggrafea1" placeholder="S????af?a? 1" /><br /><input type="text" name="syggrafea2" placeholder="S????af?a? 2"/>';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

I am pretty new to Javacript. Could anyone please help me write it properly?

Comment: Where `value` has been defined?

Comment: I think you meant `function showfield(value)` instead of `function showfield(name)`

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is function showfield(value).

Comment: Also try this `<input type="number" name="syggrafei" oninput="showfield(this.value)" />
<div id="div1"></div>`  http://jsfiddle.net/XhunN/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think it would be better if you use "Onblur" instead of "oninput" , because when user finishes changing it will perform the function.

then , easily you can use "For" to make what you want. like this , look :

```
<input id="myInput" onblur="showfield($(this).value)" />
```

Here is the Javascript code :

```
function showfield(value){
var data = '';
for ( i = 0 ; i < value ; i++ )
{
data += '<input type="text" name="syggrafea'+i+'" placeholder="Συγγραφέας '+i+'" />';
}
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=data;
}
```

:)

Comment: Thank you very much! Much better than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

`type=number` does not have options so your oninput will not work. You just want to use

```
showfield(this.value)
```